# Degrees of freedom in generalized additive model

Tags: degrees-of-freedom, generalized-additive-model

Be $y$ a quantitative response and $x$ a quantitative explanatory variable. The effective degrees of freedom of a smoothing spline are defined as:
$df=trace(S)$
where $S$ is the smoothing matrix which projects the $y$ vector to get the vector of the fitted values $\hat{y}$. 
However, in a generalized additive model, the effective degrees of freedom for the jth term are (approximately) defined as:
$df_j=trace(S_j)-1$
Can you please explain why we subtract $1$ in this case?

Be $y$ a quantitative response. Be $x_1$ and $x_2$ two quantitative explanatory variables and $x_3$ an unordered factor with 5 levels.
Consider the following additive model:
$y=\alpha+f_1(x_1)+f_2(x_2)+\beta_1*d_1+\beta_2*d_2+\beta_3*d_3+\beta_4*d_4+\epsilon$
where $d_1$,$d_2$,$d_3$,$d_4$ are 4 dummy variables to code $x_3$.
Suppose we decide to smooth $x_1$ with 4 df and $x_2$ with 5 df.
So:
$y=\alpha+s(x_1,df=4)+s(x_2,df=5)+\beta_1*d_1+\beta_2*d_2+\beta_3*d_3+\beta_4*d_4+\epsilon$

I'd say that the effective degrees of freedom of the model are:
$df_{model} =  df_{intercept}+df_{x1}+df_{x2}+df_{x3} = 1+(4-1)+(5-1)+(5-1) = 12$
However, the output tells me that the effective df of the model are 14.
Thank you in advance.